# Question about trigonometry substitution integration.

Tags: calculus, integration

For example, $\int \sqrt{16-9x^2}$. I know that to solve this you've to substitute $x=\frac{4}{3}\sin u$ (Through W.A). But how do I know what to let $x$ be when there is no W.A? Sorry for my english.

Comment: what do you mean by W.A.? :)

Comment: Wolfram Alpha....

Answer (score 1):

For these kinds of integrals, you want the expression under the square root sign to become a perfect square. In this case, the identity $\cos^2 x = 1-\sin^2 x$ comes to mind. The $\frac{4}{3}$ is there so that when you multiply $\frac{4}{3}$ by $9$, you get $16$ and are left with $16\cos^2u$.

Other useful identities for different quadratic expressions under the radicand are $\tan^2+1 = \sec^2$ and $\sec^2-1=\tan^2$.

In other situations you may first need to complete the square. Your textbook should have a discussion of all of this.